# Consultas Especiales en Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

He estado usando Cloud Firestore para mi base con puro Js, tengo un inconveniente al hacer un chat y es que necesito que dos usuarios tengan su chat creando una instancia que es solo de ellos dos.

Queda algo asi:

```
    Colec:->Mensaje
        Doc:->Mensajes
          Sub-Colec:->Mensajes-Sub
           Doc:->Este nombre se genera a partir del usuario1 y del usuario 2
            /Colec(AQUI SE INGRESAN LOS DATOS DEL MENSAJE)
             :->id_QuienEnvia, id_QuienRecibe, contenido, Nombre_QuienEnvia
```

Resulta que necesito consultar que mensajes me han enviado, para ello debo acceder donde se almacenan los mensajes -> `./Mensaje/Mensajes/Sub-Colec/Doc/Colec`
y hacer la consulta algo asi Buscame en = `./.../.../.../.../Doc` donde `id_QuienRecibe` sea igual al mio, sin embargo no logro plasmarlo en el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente no se pueden hacer consultas sobre varias colecciones por separado, tendrías que hacerlo por separado, la otra opción es que utilices cloud functions de firebase para copiar los datos que necesitas en un solo documento, en cloud functions puedes hacer algo como

```
Corporativos/{idCorporativo}/Desarrollos/{idDesarrollo}/Clusters/{idCluster}/NivelesTiposMapeos/{idNivel}
```

En el cual los documentos marcados con llaves {idDesarrollo} son dinámicos y se ejecutan cada vez que se modifican.

Haría un documento para que agrupara todos los datos requieren copiándolos en un solo documento.